# Mailgun forward to google group stopped working

Tags: mailgun

We have a google group setup to handle inbound support emails. We have mailgun setup to forward from various addr@ourdomain.com inboxes to that group. This worked fine up until recently. Now mailgun claims the delivery worked - but nothing shows up in the google group. Here is the mailgun detailed status of the message ...

```
"event": "delivered",
"delivery-status": {
    "tls": true,
    "mx-host": "aspmx.l.google.com",
    "code": 250,
    "description": "",
    "session-seconds": 0.647407054901123,
    "utf8": true,
    "attempt-no": 1,
    "message": "OK",
    "certificate-verified": true
}
```

I don't know what else to do in order to debug this - and determine where the email is going @ google?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was tied to either a new or newly-changed setting in the google group whereby all new messages were going into a pending folder to be reviewed by a group moderator (this had not previously been the case). Changing that setting to bypass the pending folder and deliver straight to the group resolved the problem.